# Drag SVG file within a div

Tags: javascript, html, svg, drag

I have an oversized svg file that I want to be able to be dragged / panned around so the users can see the whole image (which is a map.)

Here's what I have to load the svg file:

```
           <div id="stage"> 

           </div>
```

and the js:

```
$(function(){

$("#stage").load('map_02.svg',function(response){

    $(this).addClass("svgLoaded");

    if(!response){ // Error loading SVG
        $(this).html('Error loading SVG. Be sure you are running from a the http protocol (not locally)');
    }

});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You can use Snap SVG and your code will look something like this :

```
// Tux image is from creative commons, I didn't create it!

var s = Snap("#svgout"); 
var g = s.group();
var tux = Snap.load("Dreaming_tux.svg", function ( loadedFragment ) { 
                        g.append( loadedFragment ); 
                        g.hover( hoverover, hoverout );
                        g.text(300,100, 'hover over me');
                    } );  

var hoverover = function() { g.animate({ transform: 's2r45,150,150' }, 1000, mina.bounce ) };
var hoverout = function() { g.animate({ transform: 's1r0,150,150' }, 1000, mina.bounce ) };
```

You have a working example here : http://svg.dabbles.info/snaptut-load-animate.html

The library is Snap SVG with a lot of documentation & examples here : http://snapsvg.io/